# How to calculate ipAddress in extjs

Tags: extjs4, ip-address

i am working in extjs. i want to find ipaddress. i have javascript code to get ipaddress as-

```
<script language="JavaScript">
VIH_BackColor = "palegreen";
VIH_ForeColor = "navy";
VIH_FontPix = "16";
//VIH_DisplayFormat = "You are visiting from:<br>IP Address1: %%IP%%<br>Host1: %%HOST%%";
// Code for only getting ip address
VIH_DisplayFormat = "%%IP%%";
VIH_DisplayOnPage = "yes";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/visitorIPHOST.js.php"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
//alert(VIH_DisplayFormat);

if(VIH_DisplayFormat!="121.246.216.1181")
{
    alert("you are not authorized user");   
}
else
{
    alert(VIH_DisplayFormat);
}   

</script>
</HEAD>
```

So how to modify this code to work in extjs.or is there any other way in extjs to calculate ipaddress?